# Android Notification setLargeIcon() is not working

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase-cloud-messaging

i am pushing notification using firebase cloud message, everything is good except that my notification cannot showing large icon, i am using @drawable/xxxx.PNG image with 144x144 pixels and 1080x1080 have tested both and still not working

this is my code

```
String CHANNEL_ID = "my_channel_01";
            CharSequence name = "my_channel";
            String Description = "This is my channel";
            int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH;
            NotificationChannel mChannel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, name, importance);
            mChannel.setDescription(Description);
            mChannel.enableLights(true);
            mChannel.setLightColor(Color.RED);
            mChannel.enableVibration(true);
            mChannel.setVibrationPattern(new long[]{100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 400, 300, 200, 400});
            mChannel.setShowBadge(false);
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(mChannel);
            Bitmap largeIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.siublarge);
            NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                    .setLargeIcon(largeIcon)
                    .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(message) )
                    .setContentText(message);
```

Comment: Is your app in foreground when you send the FCM? I'm asking because when the app is in background `onMessageReceived` is not called for notification FCM. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive

Comment: I tired it works fine. Which drawable do you use? Drawable or Drawable-hdpi

Comment: @EugenPechanec do you mean when i am sending FCM is my app in my screen ? if that so the answer is no, i open the app and then minimize it then send the message, because when i open the app and send message it wont showing, or if you mean my notification code, then the answer is yes, i am not using ````@doInBackground````

Comment: @KasımÖzdemirwhat is Drawable-hdpi ? i never see that folder before, and i am using file inside ````@Drawable```` i dont know the difference between it